# API requests aborted

Tags: python, api

First of all, I can't expose my API keys due to privacy reasons, sorry about that. Let me know how I could better explain the situation.

On high level, here is my Python code:

```
for x in range(0, len(zone_ids)):
    time.sleep(2)
    response = requests.post(f'https://vemcount.app/api/v3/report?source=zones&data= 
    {zone_ids[x]}&data_output=count_out&period=date&form_date_from=2020-01-04&form_date_to=2020-01- 
    04&period_step=30min&show_hours_from=00:00&show_hours_to=23:45', headers=headers)
```

The problem is that, this code sometimes run successfully, sometime fails. When it fails, some IDs/requests are actually run, it just stopped in the middle of for loop for any particular "random" request. I'm pretty sure it hasn't exceeded the API rate limit of 60 requests per min as I have embedded time.sleep(2) in my for loop. Here is the message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RemoteDisconnected                        Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\envs\sa\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    698             # Make the request on the httplib connection object.
--> 699             httplib_response = self._make_request(
    700                 conn,

~\Anaconda3\envs\sa\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    444                     # Otherwise it looks like a bug in the code.
--> 445                     six.raise_from(e, None)
    446         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError, SocketError) as e:

~\Anaconda3\envs\sa\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

~\Anaconda3\envs\sa\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    439                 try:
--> 440                     httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
    441                 except BaseException as e:

~\Anaconda3\envs\sa\lib\http\client.py in getresponse(self)
   1346             try:
-> 1347                 response.begin()
   1348             except ConnectionError:

~\Anaconda3\envs\sa\lib\http\client.py in begin(self)
    306         while True:
--> 307             version, status, reason = self._read_status()
    308             if status != CONTINUE:

~\Anaconda3\envs\sa\lib\http\client.py in _read_status(self)
    275             # sending a valid response.
--> 276             raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
    277                                      " response")

RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ProtocolError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\envs\sa\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    438             if not chunked:
--> 439                 resp = conn.urlopen(
    440                     method=request.method,

~\Anaconda3\envs\sa\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    754 
--> 755             retries = retries.increment(
    756                 method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]

~\Anaconda3\envs\sa\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    530             if read is False or not self._is_method_retryable(method):
--> 531                 raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
    532             elif read is not None:

~\Anaconda3\envs\sa\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    733             if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
--> 734                 raise value.with_traceback(tb)
    735             raise value

~\Anaconda3\envs\sa\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    698             # Make the request on the httplib connection object.
--> 699             httplib_response = self._make_request(
    700                 conn,

~\Anaconda3\envs\sa\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    444                     # Otherwise it looks like a bug in the code.
--> 445                     six.raise_from(e, None)
    446         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError, SocketError) as e:

~\Anaconda3\envs\sa\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

~\Anaconda3\envs\sa\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    439                 try:
--> 440                     httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
    441                 except BaseException as e:

~\Anaconda3\envs\sa\lib\http\client.py in getresponse(self)
   1346             try:
-> 1347                 response.begin()
   1348             except ConnectionError:

~\Anaconda3\envs\sa\lib\http\client.py in begin(self)
    306         while True:
--> 307             version, status, reason = self._read_status()
    308             if status != CONTINUE:

~\Anaconda3\envs\sa\lib\http\client.py in _read_status(self)
    275             # sending a valid response.
--> 276             raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
    277                                      " response")

ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\Vzhao\repos\SocialMediaAnalytics\2_etl_scripts\Vemcount_Historical_Data.py in 
     74     s = requests.Session()
     75     s.mount('https://', MyAdapter())
---> 76     response = s.post(f'https://vemcount.app/api/v3/report?source=zones&data={zone_ids[x]}&data_output=count_out&period=date&form_date_from=2020-01-04&form_date_to=2020-01-04&period_step=30min&show_hours_from=00:00&show_hours_to=23:45', headers=headers)
     77  #  response = requests.post(f'https://vemcount.app/api/v3/report?source=zones&data={zone_ids[x]}&data_output=count_out&period=date&form_date_from=2020-01-02&form_date_to=2020-01-02&period_step=30min&show_hours_from=00:00&show_hours_to=23:45', headers=headers)
     78     vemcount = json.loads(response.text)

~\Anaconda3\envs\sa\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in post(self, url, data, json, **kwargs)
    588         """
    589 
--> 590         return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
    591 
    592     def put(self, url, data=None, **kwargs):

~\Anaconda3\envs\sa\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    540         }
    541         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 542         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    543 
    544         return resp

~\Anaconda3\envs\sa\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    653 
    654         # Send the request
--> 655         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    656 
    657         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

~\Anaconda3\envs\sa\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    496 
    497         except (ProtocolError, socket.error) as err:
--> 498             raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
    499 
    500         except MaxRetryError as e:

ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

Comment: I would first change the code to use query params properly, perhaps your current usage causes the error. See official requests documentation for query params [here](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls).

Comment: Maybe something like this: https://bugs.python.org/issue41345

Comment: If it makes sense, you can catch the failed urls with try-except to try again later.